# Github-action build for .NET Blazor MAUI

Tags: .net, github-actions, maui

We have a .NET MAUI project where we target only iOS and Android. We wanted to create BUILD github-action and we ended up with this:

```
name: Client
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
    - 'src/Client/**'
    - 'src/Shared/**'
env:
  PROJECT_PATH: path/path/mauiApp.csproj

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.405
       
    - name: Install MAUI/.NET Workloads
      run: dotnet workload install maui

    - name: Restore NuGet packages
      run: dotnet restore ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }}
        
    - name: Build MAUI Android
      run: dotnet build ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -c Release -f net6.0-android --no-restore

    - name: Build MAUI iOS
      run: dotnet build ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -c Release -f net6.0-ios --no-restore
```

but we would like to speed things up and to make it parallel with 2 jobs. Dividing the logic is not the problem. But we wanted to specify the LEAST dependencies necessary. So android buid will contain only android related resources and ios one just ios-realted

But when we tried to do install maui just for iOS like:

```
dotnet workload install maui-ios --ignore-failed-sources
```

then `dotnet restore` command afterwards fail.

So my question is, how to split these 2 builds without using in each of them whole `dotnet workload install maui` but just the maui for the platform ?

Answer (score 0):

So we ended up with this:

```
name: Client
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
    - 'src/Client/**'
    - 'src/Shared/**'
    - 'tests/Client/**'
    - 'tests/Shared/**'

env:
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: true                     # Disable the .NET logo
  DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: true # Disable the .NET first time experience
  DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: true       # Disable sending .NET CLI telemetry
  
  PROJECT_PATH: path/path/mauiApp.csproj
  BUILD_CONFIGURATION: Release

jobs:
  build-android:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.405

    - name: Install MAUI Android
      run: dotnet workload install android ios maui-android --ignore-failed-sources

    - name: Restore NuGet packages
      run: dotnet restore ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} --ignore-failed-sources

    - name: Build MAUI Android
      run: dotnet build ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -c ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} -f net6.0-android --no-restore

  build-ios:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 6.0.405

    - name: Install MAUI iOS
      run: dotnet workload install android ios maui-ios --ignore-failed-sources

    - name: Restore NuGet packages
      run: dotnet restore ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -r ios-arm64 --ignore-failed-sources 

    - name: Build MAUI iOS
      run: >
        dotnet build ${{ env.PROJECT_PATH }} -c ${{ env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION }} -f net6.0-ios --no-restore
        --p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64
```

So we achieved splitting without the use of whole `install workload maui` but there is still one unknown and that is that I dont understand the reason behing including `android` in iOS and `ios` in Android workload install but without that it simply doesnt work.

Comment: is this an answer or additional info to your question?

Comment: answer because I achieved what I wanted. But still there is one unknown. I will edit the end summary in the answer.